# Simplify expression to Abs

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[1/(a^2 b^2)], Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

gives

```
Abs[1/(a b)]
```

How do I simplify the following expression

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 + a + b)/(a^2 b^2)], Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

into 
$\frac{\sqrt{a+b+1}}{\left| a b\right| }$
?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `LeafCount` is not the complete ComplexityFunction used by `Simplify` it is a good first order approximation, and you can see that your expressions are equivalent under this metric:

```
expr1 = Sqrt[(1 + a + b)/(a^2 b^2)];
expr2 = Sqrt[a + b + 1]/Abs[a b];

LeafCount /@ {expr1, expr2}
```

> ```
> {15, 15}
> ```

In your particular case merely using `StringLength` works:

```
FullSimplify[expr1, {a, b} \[Element] Reals, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength @ ToString @ # &)]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[1 + a + b]/Abs[a b]
> ```