# Assumptions within Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am using the ratio between two error probabilities in various functions. I want *Mathematica* to display this ratio in the most simple manner. How do I let *Mathematica* know that, in this case, the simplest manner is as the top line in the picture below? How do I let *Mathematica* factor the expression into `(e1)`, `(e2)`, `(1 - e1)` and `(1 - e2)`?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89eol.png]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Next time post the actual code instead of a picture, that makes it quicker for people to try it out and answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

When `Simiplify` isn't doing what you want, always have a look at the `FullForm` to see why:

```
(1 - e1)/(1 - e2) // FullForm
(* Times[Plus[1, Times[-1, e1]], Power[Plus[1, Times[-1, e2]], -1]] *)

(-1 + e1)/(-1 + e2) // FullForm
(* Times[Plus[-1, e1], Power[Plus[-1, e2], -1]] *)
```

We see that it's related to `-1` being very simple while `-e2` is actually `-1 * e2` we could use this to construct an appropriate [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) but in many cases [`StringLength @ ToString @ # &`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23445/1517) is easier and gives good results:

```
StringLength@ToString[(1 - e1)/(1 - e2)]
(* 20 *)

StringLength@ToString[(-1 + e1)/(-1 + e2)]
(* 23 *)

Simplify[(-1 + e1)/(-1 + e2),
 ComplexityFunction :> (StringLength @ ToString @ # &)
 ]
(* (1 - e1)/(1 - e2) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(-1 + e1)/(-1 + e2) // TraditionalForm // StandardForm
```

> (e1-1)/(e2-1)

```
Simplify[(-1 + e1)/(-1 + e2), 
 ComplexityFunction :> (LeafCount@# + 10 Count[#, -1 + _, -1] &)]
```

> (1 - e1)/(1 - e2)